# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' config is not set. Bind key 'None' is not in 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' config

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and Python and I don't understand why it gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Lucía\Documents\TFG\herfontsistemas-app\herfontsistemas-back\index.py", line 6, in <module>
    db.create_all()
      File "C:\Users\Lucía\Documents\TFG\herfontsistemas-app\herfontsistemas-back\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 868, in create_all
        self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
      File "C:\Users\Lucía\Documents\TFG\herfontsistemas-app\herfontsistemas-back\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 846, in _call_for_binds
        raise sa.exc.UnboundExecutionError(message) from None
    sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' config is not set. Bind key 'None' is not in 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' config.
```

This is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from routes.contacts import contacts
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:lucia@localhost/herfontsistemasdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False

SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(contacts)
```

This is my index.py:

```
from app import app
from utils.db import db

#Cuando arranque la aplicacion creará las tablas dee contact.py
with app.app_context(): 
    db.create_all()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my contact.py:

```
from utils.db import db


class Contact(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombreCompleto = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    telefono = db.Column(db.String(100))
    def __init__(self,nombreCompleto,email,telefono):
        self.nombreCompleto=nombreCompleto
        self.email=email
        self.telefono=telefono
    enter code here
```

This is my db.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db=SQLAlchemy()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy version > 3.

You do not have to create your SQLAlchemy(app) in your app.py file. I would give the following a try.

index.py:

```
from app import app
from utils.db import db

#Cuando arranque la aplicacion creará las tablas dee contact.py

#ADD THIS LINE HERE
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context(): 
    db.create_all()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:lucia@localhost/herfontsistemasdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
```

See here for more information on how to set up the app in Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.x: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:lucia@localhost/herfontsistemasdb'
<b>
`# Add Secret Key!`
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "custom key"
`# create the extension`
db=SQLAlchemy()
`# Initialize The Database`
db.init_app(app)
</b>
`#Make A Model or Schema Like`

class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    # we add new column with need migrate
    address = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    # Create aString
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Name %r>' % self.name


with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```